# Angular test - observable with different return values

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to test a component that on her ngOnInit subscribe to observable in a service, and change the behavior of the component according to the value got from the observable. I reduced my problem to these pieaces of code.

the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <div>
    <h3>currentValue is {{currentValue}}</h3>
    <div>
      <button (click)="changeTo(true)">true</button>
      <button (click)="changeTo(false)">false</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public currentValue: boolean;

  constructor(
    private appService: AppService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getObs().subscribe(newValue => this.currentValue = newValue);
  }

  changeTo(value: boolean) {
    this.appService.setObs(value);
  }
}
```

the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {
    private obs = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    getObs(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.obs.asObservable();
    }

    setObs(value: boolean): void {
        this.obs.next(value);
    }
}
```

the test:

```
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let mockAppService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['setObs', 'getObs']);

  let app: AppComponent
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: AppService, useValue: mockAppService }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    mockAppService.getObs.and.returnValue(of(false));
    app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {

    expect(app).toBeTruthy(); // pass
  });

  it('should set currentValue to false', () => {

    expect(app.currentValue).toBe(false); // pass
  });

  it('should change currentValue to true', () => 
    mockAppService.// some how to do next(true)
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(app.currentValue).toBe(true); // 
  });
});
```

I expect to have an easy way to control the values that the mockObservable returned. I want to change the value between tests and test each of the options.

I saw the option of jasmine-marbles but it looks to complicated for such an issue. Does any one know an easy way to do that?

EDIT: I want to have the ability to call next() on the observale, without calling setObs (lets say it's private, actually in my app I don't have setObs function, the call for next() is in more complex function)

Answer (score 0):

Your component calls `getObs()` in `ngOnInit()`. Your test calls `fixture.detectChanges()` in the `beforeEach` block. And the first call to `detectChanges()` causes `ngOnInit()` to be called.

So changing the behavior of `getObs()` in the test won't change anything. It's too late. The component has already called it and subscribed before that, when the beforeEach block was executed.

Move the call to the first `fixture.detectChanges()` *inside* the test function, and make sure to stub the service (tell what getObs() must return) *before* calling `fixture.detectChanges()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for something slight different. I edit my question. I want to do something like next() to change the value during a test, not just to initilize it with different value

Comment: Then mock the AppService and replace it with a fake implementation that does exactly the same thing as the real one you posted: return a Subject, that you can control by calling its next() method whenever you want.